# Is there a way to get the number of lines of code from a commit object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

For a project, I am supposed to determine the number of lines of code in each of the commits of a .py program (repository is using git). However, I am unsure how to access that information from Jupyter Notebook, in which this project's code is to be written. Is there some method or attribute that I can use to extract that information directly from the commit object?

Comment: Git commits have a reference to the 'tree', which is the entire state of the file. So, to get a diff, you need to compare that tree to the "parent"-tree of the commit. There is probably something built in for this. If you want just the line count at a given commit, get the tree, locate the file and get the content.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the "lines of code" *changed* (added, deleted, modified) for each commit?